# What are references for a second course in PDEs?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I am interested in a slightly more advanced text in PDEs. I studied PDEs using Strauss' "Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction" and Farlow's "Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers". I have heard of Evans' book by I think it might be too advanced for my at this stage as my background is in engineering and not in mathematics. I am interested in something that helps me build my theoretical understanding,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, due to its content (which includes introduction to Sobolev spaces, Galerkin method and semigroups), Part II of Evans (Chapters 5, 6 and 7) is a excellent source for a second course. In a sense, the approach is really introductory because it is done without the notion of distribution. However, I agree that it can be a hard reading (which doesn't mean you shouldn't try).

As an alternative with similar content (including introduction to distributions,  Sobolev spaces, Galerkin method and semigroups), my suggestion is [*An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Partial_Differential.html?id=0RmDjrFO3CUC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y) by Renardy and Rogers. Maybe, you should start from Chapter 5. Note that chapters 6 and 8 are, basically, review of functional analysis (of course, focused on what will be needed) and thus the reading can become easier (in Evans book, the results and concepts from functional analysis are in the appendices without proofs or exercises).

Comment: This might be asking too much, but how would you recommend reading Evans? As in a roadmap for a first reader

Comment: @dleal I'd recommend it based on my personal experience. My first course in PDE was Part I of Evans and my second course in PDE was Part II of Evans. This is why I agree the reading can be hardy and why I believe it is good. However, my case was not self-study. Of course I read other books (even before the second course), but only for specific subjects and not for a comprehensive approach. So, in a sense, Evans is the unique "introductory text on PDE" that I read. But in fact, probably Evans is not the best roadmap for self-study.